# List wild repos I have access to with gitolite

Tags: gitolite

I have installed gitolite and switched on wild repos. With a rule for
    repo    u/CREATOR/\w.*
I can indeed create repos as I expect. But how can I list them to see which ones already exist? With

```
ssh gitolite@SERVER info
```

I only see the "normal" repos and a "C R W" line for all the wild repos. I don't see any individual wild repos I have already created, and I also don't see any wild repos others have created and given me access to (with setperm). Can I list them all?

(Caveat: I'm using gitolite 2.3.1 because it is the version packed in an rpm. Has this changed in a later version?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this has changed. With Gitolite 3 this works as I hoped it would.